# What happens to the data that is passed to and from a background worker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

What happens to the data that is passed to and from a background worker?

Data is passed from the main thread to the background worker using RunWorkerAsync:

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(myData);
```

This is received in the DoWork event handler in the background thread:

```
myData = (Data)e.Argument;
```

After DoWork has processed the data, it returns it using e.Result:

```
e.Result = myData;
```

This is received in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler in the main thread:

```
myData = (Data)e.Result;
```

BackgroundWorker is taking care of passing the data between the threads. I am expecting to pass large amounts of data to and from a background worker so I want to know what the overhead of this transfer is, and if there is a better way of processing a large amount of in-memory objects in a background worker. I would also like to know it is possible to access the data in the background worker from the main thread in a thread-safe manner.

For reference, I am using C#, .Net 3.5 and Windows Forms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There really is no overhead (provided `Data` is a class), since only the reference is passed around.  The data itself isn't "copied" into a thread - all threads can access the data in the process (for the most part).

> I would also like to know it is possible to access the data in the background worker from the main thread in a thread-safe manner.

Yes, it's possible to access the data, but in order to do it in a thread-safe manner, you'll need to manage the synchronization yourself.  This typically requires something like a `lock`, though there are many options depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: +1 for answering the multi-thread syncing part of the question.

Answer (score 5):

Objects are *always* passed by reference.  There is no overhead whatsoever.

`BackgroundWorker` simply adds the object to an internal queue, then reads it off the queue on the UI thread.  (This is actually done by `Control.MarshaledInvoke`)

Comment: @Reed: He said `Object`s, which implies boxing for value types.  But the wording of the answer is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially no overhead in the transfer; it is just an object reference (there's no sort of marshaling of the data involved).  You are thread safe as long as the main thread does not access the data between the call to RunWorkerAsync and RunWorkerCompleted.